# Is there a way to represent all types of private keys as regex? (It doesnt matter if they are valid or not)

Tags: python, regex, encryption, private-key

I am writing a program to check through an array of strings to see if it has one of the following in it;
1. Private Keys
2. BIP 39 Seeds (12, 18 and 24 words)

I already can check for a WIF private key but I have no Idea how to represent anything that remotely looks like a private key (WIF, Extended Format/ECDSA, Mini, Parent Private Key) with Regex.
If you don't think Regex is the way to go, you can suggest something else to me, keep in mind that I don't need to verify that it actually exists and I don't need something overly complicated.

For checking for BIP 39 Seeds, I have a function below that slices the string list in turns of 12,18 and 24 and compares each slice to a string list of all 2048 words in BIP39 but it doesn't seem to work.

Code for checking for WIF looks like this and it works, the code has a larger part but I don't want to complicate things, just bringing out what is needed.

```
z = "5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAbuatmU"

exp = bool(re.match(r"^[5KL][1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{48,51}$", z))
   if exp == True:
      print ("Found Private Key with regex")
   else
      print ("Didnt find a WIF but other keys might still be in it")
```

Here is the code for verifying it contains a bip39 seed

```
for m in (global_array):

    try:
      new_array = global_array[m:12]
      if set(new_array).issubset(set(bip39_list)) == True:
         print("Possible 12 - Word BIP 39 seed found!")
         print(new_array)
      except:
         continue
     continue

     try:
       new_array = global_array[m:18]
       if set(new_array).issubset(set(bip39_list)) == True:
         print("Possible 18 - Word BIP 39 seed found!")
         print(new_array)
      except:
         continue
       continue

      try:
        new_array = global_array[m:24]
        if set(new_array).issubset(set(bip39_list)) == True:
          print("Possible 24 - Word BIP 39 seed found!")
          print(new_array)
       except:
         continue
  continue
```

A sample data that contains everything im looking for would be;

```
global_array = ["5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAbuatmU", "KziXBfNy2eZEKHdZeBZQ3ZyW3joXcv2k66yHuKPaDgNwEX76wMPU", "await", "abandon", "actress", "actual", "adapt", "satoshi", "advance", "advice", "aerobic", "admit","afraid","again","age","zola", "zolof", "yada", "yada"]
```

I would like a way to be able to correctly check for `bip39` as the one I have done above does not work.
I would like a way to check for all types of private keys, not just wif.

I would also like if anyone can add a way to rewrite this as a multi-threaded with a long list of about 10,000 files.

Comment: Here You are matching the format of WIF keys as described in the documentation. So, basically, You would need to create a regex for every possible format of key that You want to match, which does not seem easy to do. One possible way You could try is to simply verify whether the given String is proper hex string of given length.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I could try that, and I assume that every type of key must be a string that is a proper hex string of given length?

Comment: This really depends, You can have a key stored as a hexadecimal String and then the method should work. But sometimes You also use various encodings in this case mostly base64 encoding. In Your case the WIF private keys are encoded with base58 encoding thus as You can see they contains letters that are not valid for hex (every letter out of A-Z range). So possibly You would need to decode the keys to hex or try to match encoded keys too.